# gtest/gmock override call from base class

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to overide a base method but it fails. class B derives from A and I need to override the call to `value`. I can't change A or B. How to fix this in a proper way? Any ideas?

```
class A {
protected:
    virtual void print(std::string s) = 0;
    std::string value()
    {
        return "A: ";
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void print(std::string s)
    {
        std::cout << value() << s << std::endl;
    }
};

class M : public B {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(std::string, value, ());
};

TEST(Test, test)
{
    M m;

    EXPECT_CALL(m, value())
        .WillRepeatedly(::testing::Return("M: "));

    m.print("test mock");
}
```

The output is: `A: test mock`

Comment: You can't do it, `value()` is not virtual. But you can mock `print()`. BTW the class design is very bad. The protected `print()` is nonsense, it can't be used in the polymorphism.

Comment: I have to test the existing 'print()' function so it makes no sense to mock this too.

Comment: Then it's not possible without changing `A` or `B`. You have to make your class testable in order to test it.